# Why am I getting "Permission denied" when activating a venv?

Tags: python, macos

I just started a new python project and created a venv inside the project folder by running `virtualenv venv` in the terminal. However, when I run `venv/bin/activate` I get a permission denied error.

I have tried

```
sudo chown -R user:user project/venv
```

but I get

```
chown: user: illegal group name
```

I have set these venvs up a ton of times and never had the issue. Is there anything else I can try?

I am on a Mac.

Comment: are you sure it's not `user:users`?

Comment: Have you typed the whole command? `source venv/bin/activate` don't forget the **source** part

Answer (score 528, accepted):

You need to run

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

or

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

The `activate` file is deliberately not executable because it must be sourced.

It must be sourced because it needs to make changes to the environment. If it is run as a script, it will only make changes to the environment of the child process used to run the script.

Someone in the comments asked about the `.` command. From the [man page for bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

```
    .  filename [arguments]
   source filename [arguments]
          Read  and execute commands from filename in the current shell
          environment and return the exit status of the last command
          executed from filename.
```

In short, `.` is a shell built-in that means the same thing as the `source` built-in.

Comment: I had to add to ``~/.zshrc`` the line ``export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=`` and then it worked. Important was without value. 
zsh 5.7 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0) on OSX 10.13.6

Comment: this is a little buried in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments in the table about halfway down the page

Comment: Why is StackOverflow a better documentation than Python's own docs is beyond me 

Answer (score 22):

On my VSC, I used these and it worked.

```
python3 -m venv .venv

source .venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 18):

**source** venv/bin/activate

### **source** venv/bin/activate

[activated successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOEkp.png)
'source' command need to add  before full path of activation file.

### Ex.

- source   *your_project_folder_path*/venv/bin/activate

### **

### if you're inside project folder then following command-

- *source  venv/bin/activate*

---

note: I've created the virtual environment folder called  `venv` If your name is different then write that name instead of writing venv

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! While IN my project's folder, `source env/bin/activate` worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:`. venv/bin/activate`

Answer (score 5):

[image]From within the virtual environment folder can type:

```
source ./bin/activate
```

and yes if you run into the permission issue then go one folder up and do the
**source ./foldervirtualenvironment/bin/activate**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30474573)

Answer (score -1):

Go to the root of the project and try this :

`. ./env/bin/activate`

worked for me.

Answer (score -6):

From the command line root enter:

```
source /home/<your_username>/<app_folder>/<venv_name>/bin/activate
```

Worked for me

Answer (score -7):

Basically, it's looking for permission to execute activate on the created folder path.

On the root give below permissions command on the desired path where activate is located

```sh
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/tensorflow/* # or whatever the target structure
```

This will extend all the permissions including Read/Write/Execute and group

then execute  `~/bin/activate`

Comment: You DO NOT want to make the activate script executable. Running that script as a child process will not make the necessary changes to the environment. Subsequent actions made with the mistaken belief that the environment has been changed could potentially lead to the loss of important data. This answer should be deleted.

Answer (score -8):

go to activate file right click and open properties-->permissions

and check Execute

open this image:

[image]