# How to activate a conda environment on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, conda

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546774/how-to-activate-conda-environment-in-jenkins-build?lq=1) question, but I am running on RHEL 7.3, not Windows.

With this simple Jenkins shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH
echo $HOME
source /app/local/anaconda3/bin/activate py35_myenv
```

I am getting this failure:

```
$ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins5945453203311093000.sh
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/teradata/client/15.10/bin:/app/local/anaconda3/bin:/opt/teradata/client/15.10/bin:/app/local/anaconda3/bin
/home/jenkins
/tmp/jenkins5945453203311093000.sh: line 4: /app/local/anaconda3/bin/activate: Permission denied
```

I tried `chmod`ing the `/app/local/anaconda3/bin/activate` file to 664 (was originally 660), but that did not help. Also tried `chmod -R o+rx /app/local/anaconda3/envs/py35_myenv` (executables under there were originally 770, now 775). That also did not help. The reason I tried that is because I am getting "Permission denied" complaints and the `jenkins` user on this machine does not belong to the group that these Anaconda files are in.

I tried adding `#!/bin/bash` to the beginning of my Jenkins script, per the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756728/cannot-activate-python-virtual-env-in-jenkins-shell-script), but that did not help.

Regular, non-Jenkins users, can activate this conda environment just fine. I am trying to have Jenkins run automated scripts out of this environment but I cannot activate it within a Jenkins job.

EDIT: If I do not provide the full path to `activate`, I get "activate: No such file or directory" complaints.

EDIT: The reason `activate` is given a `chmod` of 664 (non-executable) is stated on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554864/permission-denied-when-activating-venv). `activate` must be non-executable and run via `source` so it can make changes to the environment.

Jenkins version: 2.129-1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod` 664 does not give you execute permission. You can explicitly specify in a `chmod` command which privileges do you want to grant or revoke. It's a bit more readable. Try changing your script to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH
echo $HOME
/app/local/anaconda3/bin/activate py35_myenv
chmod ug+x /app/local/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

You can use https://chmodcommand.com to verify it the command does what you're expecting.

Also, it can be an issue if `jenkins` user does not have access to one of the script's parent folder. Try to set the same permissions to parent folders as well. The following commands are from your code snippet in the comments:

```
sudo find . -perm 770 -exec chmod o+rx {}; \
sudo find . -perm 750 -exec chmod o+rx {}; \
sudo find . -perm 660 -exec chmod o+r {}; \
sudo find . -perm 640 -exec chmod o+r {}
```

Comment: Right, I know that `chmod` 664 does not give executable permissions. That is why I must `source` the calling of `activate`, rather than executing `activate` directly. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45554982/2491761): "The `activate` file is deliberately not executable because it must be sourced. It must be sourced because it needs to make changes to the environment. If it is run as a script, it will only make changes to the environment of the child process used to run the script."

Comment: Also can be an issue if jenkins user does not have acces to one of the script's parent folder. Try to set same permissions to parent folders as well.

Comment: Thank you! It was a problem with the permissions of parent folders. Along with "sibling" folders in the Anaconda installation. Fix: (from anaconda3 directory) `sudo find . -perm 770 -exec chmod o+rx {} \; 
sudo find . -perm 750 -exec chmod o+rx {} \; 
sudo find . -perm 660 -exec chmod o+r {} \; 
sudo find . -perm 640 -exec chmod o+r {} \; `

Comment: would you mind moving your comment to the answer? I can then accept it

Comment: Thanks, I just did. Also, let me know if something needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines to the Executed shell in Jenkins because bash shell does not support `conda init`.

```
export PATH=/path/to/anaconda3/bin:$PATH # modify this path 
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate your_env # change your_env based on your env name
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide the unnecessary output if not needed:

```
steps {
            sh """
                #!/usr/bin/env bash
                set +x
                source /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
                conda activate env-p38
                echo $PATH
                set -x
                """
  }
```